# Is there a way of creating a shorthand map to be passed to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, arguments

I wonder if there is a way of constructing a temporary map to be passed so that the following implementation is possible:

```
void func(map<string,int> & input) {
    cout << input["m1"] << endl;  
    cout << input["m2"] << endl;
}

func ( map<string,int>{{"m1",1},{"m2",2}}  ; // causing error when compiled
```

Comment: Well that error is first because you forgot a closing `)`.

Comment: You're trying to bind an rvalue expression to a non-const lvalue reference. Additionally you're missing a `)`.

Comment: you should include the error message in the quesiton. Usually it holds useful information, often hints on how to fix. It should tell you that you cannot pass a temporary to the function (perhaps in difficult to understand language). Fix for that is to pass it as `const&`. Then you will get an error for using `[]` that tells you that there is not `const` overload. Fix for that is to use `std::map::find`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're trying to bind an rvalue expression to an *lvalue reference to non-const `std::map`*.

To **solve** this you can add a **low-level** `const` in the parameter and use `std::map::find` as shown below:

```
void func(const std::map<string, int>& input) {
    auto it1 = input.find("m1");
    
    if(it1!=input.end())
    {
         cout << it1->second << endl; 
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"element cannot be found"<<std::endl;
    }
    //do the same for other key "m2"    
}
int main()
{
    func({{"m1", 1}, {"m2", 2}});
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gqWBAa5pv)

---

Note if you want to just print all the elements of the map you can use **structure binding** with C++17 as shown below:

```
void func(const std::map<string, int>& input) {
    for(const auto&[key, value]: input)
    {
        std::cout<<key<<" --> "<<value<<std::endl;
    }    
}
int main()
{
    func({{"m1", 1}, {"m2", 2}});
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo C++17 & above](https://onlinegdb.com/ZR5NRb8ca)

---

Note structure bindings are available from C++17, so if you're using C++11 or C++14 you can use the range-based for loop :

```
void func(const std::map<string, int>& input) {
    for(const auto&element: input)
    {
        std::cout<<element.first<<" --> "<<element.second<<std::endl;
    }  
}
```

[Demo Prior C++17](https://onlinegdb.com/wSMS7Hc58)

Comment: in C++ 11 and up, you can always also for-range over the std::pairs in the map, `for (const auto& mypair : input) { std::cout << mypair.first << " --> " << mypair.second << "\n"; }`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, mentioned it at the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks, looks really nice. I'd argue `.at` instead of your `find`/`else` methodology would be fine here, as it looks to me as if the absence here would semantically be understood as an exception, and hence, throwing might totally be OK, but I like the "safe approach" here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, as your answer already explains the `.at` approach i explained the `find` approach. I also choose to use `find` because i wanted that if there is no such key in the map then instead of throwing an exception(which `at` does) we can just print out that there is no such key/element inside the map. Now, OP can choose whichever method they found suitable according to their needs.

Comment: yep as said, I like how your answer is structured and it is really a nice thing to have next to mine!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, that's easily possible, you just need to make your `func` accept temporary (rvalue) values.

You don't need to modify the map, so

```cpp
void func(const std::map<string, int>& input) {
    cout << input.at("m1") << endl;  
    cout << input.at("m2") << endl;
}
func({{"m1", 1}, {"m2", 2}});
```

should do.

Note that, as comfortable as they are, `[]` of map *modifies* the map (if there key is not in there before, it's inserted and a value is value-initialized). So, you can't use it on const references.

The way around that is passing in the map as special rval ref, `&&` :

```cpp
void func(map<string,int>&& input) {
    cout << input["m1"] << endl;  
    cout << input["m2"] << endl;
}
```

However, that is not always the right thing to do, and I do prefer the const & approach when the function really has no need to modify the parameter, as it actually makes compile-time guarantees that this won't happen, even on complex objects.

Comment: does not  compile

Comment: true, the `[]` won't do, use `.at()`.

Comment: Should be fixed, compiles for me.

Comment: the mappedvalue inserted by `[]` is value-initialized, not default-initialized.

Comment: ah true, sorry.